# How to add an external module to my application in kviy while using buildozer to make an apk

Tags: parse-platform, kivy

Thanks in advance.

I am making an app using Kivy and background cloud as parse. I have installed ParsePy from https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy on my system and it works fine for my app on my PC.

The problem is that though ParsePy has a pip installation but its not a default Pipy module which can directly be installed using pip function. So how to put this module in my app if I am using buildozer to convert the app to apk.

Can you also tell me how to make it running using the Kivy launcher.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a pure python module, just copy the module to your app directory. It will be included just like all the other python code in your app.

Comment: Thanks its working included the parse_rest folder and it workslike magic